# Is there a way to launch Voice Control programmatically on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, controls, voice

Is there a way to launch Voice Control programmatically just like you can launch Safari? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other apps can be opened only if there is a URL scheme they've registered.  This is how you can open Safari or Mail or even Maps programmatically, but not arbitrary applications.  The list of Apple supported applications with URL schemes are documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Unfortunately, Voice Control does not have a documented URL scheme, so it cannot be launched programmatically.